# Why am I getting 404 errors in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-url

I can't understand why I'm getting 404 errors in CodeIgniter.

My default controller works perfectly:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('home');

    }

}
```

But my other controller is not working (I get a 404 when I try to access its URL):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Add extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('add');


    }
}
```

Here's some other helpful information:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['base_url'] = '';
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I'm working on localhost and all the other controllers from my other applications are working perfectly. This is the 1st time I have this problem.

Comment: Does the filename is starting with upper case?

Comment: @Joerg Actually no. My controllers are home.php and add.php.

Comment: In Codeigniter 3 the controler file names should start with upper case. Give it a try, I hope it helps.

Comment: It didn't work and I'm not actually using the latest version of CodeIgniter :/

Answer (score -1):

If there is no controller class, it should show a 404 not found error. Also try controller file name start with a cap.

refer this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422033/codeigniter-2-1-issue-with-show-404-and-404-override)